# KDB get last/first day of quarter

Tags: kdb

How can I get last or first day of quarter for given date.

I was trying something like

C:"d"$3 xbar "m"$

C .z.d

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function seems to work for the first day of the quarter

```
qfirst:"d"$3 xbar "m"$ 
qfirst .z.d
2019.01.01
```

In order to get the last day of the quarter you need to amend it slightly

```
qlast: -1+"d"$3+3 xbar "m"$
qlast .z.d
2019.03.31
```

In order to make the function faster, you can write the function as a lambda, rather than as a projection.

```
lambdaqfirst:{"d"$3 xbar "m"$x}
\ts:1000000 lambdaqfirst .z.d
1583 560
\ts:1000000 qfirst .z.d
1897 528
```

Comment: Hi Ganesh- what do you expect the output of `qfirst 2018.10.01`? Are you getting an error or are you getting `2018.10.01` ?